# Div slider doesn't work - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently created a simple image slider here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/test2/

Which has basically a next and prev buttons and slides the image. You can check the codes of that here: https://jsfiddle.net/mmytscuz/

And now I am trying to apply these codes to my new element but this time instead of images I am trying to apply it using div elements.

You can check my current progress work here: https://jsfiddle.net/7808uLpv/

So basically when you click the next button it must slide up on the next list item element. For some reason it won't hide the other elements now also it doesn't slide either.

So far here's how I layout my elements:

```
<ul class="slider">

<li>
  <div class="box center">
  <h1>What is your name?</h1>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name.."/>
    <div id="slider-nav">
        <button data-dir="next" >Next &raquo;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="box center">
  <h1>How much money do you have?</h1>
  <input type="text" name="money" placeholder="Your Money.."/>
  <div id="slider-nav">
    <button data-dir="next" >Next &raquo;</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="box center">
  <h1>Your Birthday?</h1>
  <input type="text" name="bday" placeholder="Your Birthday.."/>
  <div id="slider-nav">
    <button data-dir="next" >Next &raquo;</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</li>

</ul>
```

And here's my javascript:

```
(function() {
 var container = $('div.slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
   slider = new Slider( container, $('#slider-nav') );

 slider.nav.find('button').on('click', function() {
   slider.setCurrent( $(this).data('dir') );
   slider.transition();
 });
})();


function Slider( container, nav ) {
    this.container = container;
    this.nav = nav.show();

    this.imgs = this.container.find('img');
    this.imgWidth = this.imgs[0].width; // 600
    this.imgsLen = this.imgs.length;

    this.current = 0;
}

Slider.prototype.transition = function( coords ) {
    this.container.animate({
        'margin-left': coords || -( this.current * this.imgWidth )
    });
};

Slider.prototype.setCurrent = function( dir ) {
    var pos = this.current;

    pos += ( ~~( dir === 'next' ) || -1 );
    this.current = ( pos < 0 ) ? this.imgsLen - 1 : pos % this.imgsLen;

    return pos;
};
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong when I click the 'NEXT' button why the elements are not sliding as well why are they all showing up at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your fiddle.

1. No jQuery loaded.
2. No `div.slider` that you refer to for plugin initialization.
3. You use id `slider-nav` like a class. Id must be unique.
4. In css `li.slider` needs to be `.slider li`
5. You're looking for images within `js` but there are none in the markup.
6. Consequently, your plugin is throwing errors, trying to detect width of these images that don't exist: `this.imgs[0].width;`

Imo, just start over, get a solid `html` and `css` base and only then try to write the `js` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Just add jQuery because without not working.See the Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mmytscuz/1/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```